pagination with arrows not working on typescipt
im doing a small project which has a table of customers
the table is displaying 10 customers in each page
also there are arrows under the table to guide the user to go and see the rest of the customers
the problem now is the arrows are not working propberly
what i want is when user clicks on the right arrow the result should display 11-21
here is my code
interface ReturnCustomer {
  entryId: string;
  name: string;
  orgId: number;
  id: number;
}


interface CustomerData {
  entryId: string;
  name: string;
  orgId: number;
  id: number;
}

const CustomerList = ({ apiData }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
     const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({ page: 0, pageSize: 10 })
    const [data, setData] = useState<ReturnCustomer[]>([])
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res: any = await auth.getcustomer({
          start: (paginationModel.page - 1) * paginationModel.pageSize,
          finish: paginationModel.page * paginationModel.pageSize,
        });
        setData(transformData(res.data.data.customers));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching customers:', error);
        setData([]); // Clear data on error
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [auth, paginationModel]);

  const transformData = (customers: any[]): CustomerData[] => {
    return customers.map((customer) => ({
      id: customer.entryId, // Use entryId as id
      entryId: customer.entryId,
      name: customer.name,
      orgId: customer.orgId,
    }));
  };
  

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    setPaginationModel((prevPaginationModel) => ({
      ...prevPaginationModel,
      page: prevPaginationModel.page + 1,
    }));
  };

  const handlePrevPage = () => {
    if (paginationModel.page > 1) {
      setPaginationModel((prevPaginationModel) => ({
        ...prevPaginationModel,
        page: prevPaginationModel.page - 1,
      }));
    }
  };

  
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={6}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Card>
          {/* FOR DISPLAYING */}
          <TableHeader value={value} handleFilter={handleFilter} toggle={toggleAddCustomerDrawer} />
          <DataGrid
            autoHeight
            rows={data}
            columns={columns}
            checkboxSelection
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            pageSizeOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
            paginationModel={paginationModel}
            onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
          />
        </Card>
      </Grid>


What is auth? Have you tried removing auth for the dependencies from useEffect?

auth is for fetching the API
the data should be saved in an API

If your arrows are inside DataGrid don't they need handleNextPage and handlePrevPage passed to them? I think you can also get rid of the [page, setPage] state since you're handling that in paginationModel. Also since you're initialising paginationModel.page to 0 I think you don't need (paginationModel.page - 1) * paginationModel.pageSize in your data fetch.

  const dataSliceStart = paginationModel.page * paginationModel.pageSize;
  const dataSliceEnd = dataSliceStart + paginationModel.pageSize;
  const slicedData = allData.slice(dataSliceStart, dataSliceEnd);

this was the solution
